# Async await promise.all and multiple APIs

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I wanna make  a list with pokemons and picture next to each name. i get list from api then combine all names to general APi adress and make array of fetches. My problem was returned list was unordered to order it there is asyns await and console.log name(process function). but it doesn't work/ could you help me with that?
[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/DeanWinchester88/pen/ExvxdxX)

```
        (async function(){  
        await Promise.all(arrForFetch)
                     .then(async files  =>{
                     for(let i = 0; i < files.length;  i++){
                      // console.log("files", files[i])
                      process(  await files[i].json())
                    }
                   //   files.forEach(  file =>{
                   //   console.log("files", file)
                   //   process(  file.json() )
                   // })
                  // .catch(err  =>  console.log("tobie pizda ucziekaj"))
                   })
                    .catch(err  =>  console.log("tobie pizda ucziekaj"))
            
          })();
          let process =   (prom)  => {
              prom.then(  data =>{
              console.log(data.id)
            })
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the return value of `Promise.all` will maintain the order that is given. So, in your case, after the `Promise.all` for `arrForFetch` finishes, you WILL have an ordered array of response data.

It seems you are trying to convert this response data to `JSON` format and then display the IDs of individual pokemon. You can use a `Promise.all` here as well. I modified your implementation a bit in the following piece of code:

```
          let arrForFetch = pokeNames.map(elem  => fetch(" https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+`${elem}` )    );

          //multiple APis fetching
          Promise.all(arrForFetch).then((jsonData) => {

            // creating array to convert each of the data entries to JSON format
            let JsonConversionArray = jsonData.map(data => data.json());
            
            // Using Promise.all similar to previous implementation.
            Promise.all(JsonConversionArray).then((data) => {
              const idArray = data.map((pokemon) => pokemon.id);
              console.log(idArray);
            })

          }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          })
```

However, if you prefer your own solution i.e. without a `Promise.all` for the JSON conversion, you can do it as follows:

```
          let arrForFetch = pokeNames.map(elem  => fetch(" https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/"+`${elem}` )    );
          //multiple APis fetching
          Promise.all(arrForFetch).then((files) => {
            
            // Iterating through files array
            for (let i=0; i<files.length; i++) {

              // You need not use await here because you are already using a then
              // clause in the process() function
              process(files[i].json())

            }
            
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
    
          // Function to display the id of the pokemon from the JSON
          function process (prom) {
            prom.then(data => { console.log(data.id) })
          }
```

Comment: thank you. that works/ wow. i will need to spend some time to understand how u did put the things but works. thank you